# close the included file in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change pro_id in MySQL query by passing the  pro_id through method.It is printing table.But it is giving

> NOTICE: CONSTANT SERVER ALREADY DEFINED IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\DASHBOARD\CONFIG2.PHP ON LINE 2
>   
> NOTICE: CONSTANT USERNAME ALREADY DEFINED IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\DASHBOARD\CONFIG2.PHP ON LINE 3
> NOTICE: CONSTANT PASSWORD ALREADY DEFINED IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\DASHBOARD\CONFIG2.PHP ON LINE 4
> NOTICE: CONSTANT DATABASE ALREADY DEFINED IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\DASHBOARD\CONFIG2.PHP ON LINE 5

these errors.

My code is like this,

```
<?php
// Defining function
function project($a){

            echo '<DOCTYPE html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Dashboard/css/table_css.css">

            </head>
            <section>
            <body>';

         include("C:\wamp64\www\DashBoard\Config2.php");

          $sql = "select total_tc,passed,failed,blocked, (total_tc-passed-failed-blocked) as notrun from (select * from (select version_id as version_id from testcases) as t0, (select count(tc_id) as total_tc from testcases where testcases.pro_id=$a) as t,(select count(tc_result) as passed from executions join testcases on testcases.id=executions.parent_id where tc_result='p' and testcases.pro_id=$a  )as t2,
                        (select count(tc_result) as failed from executions join testcases on testcases.id=executions.parent_id where tc_result='f' and testcases.pro_id=$a)as t3,(select count(tc_result) as blocked from executions join testcases on testcases.id=executions.parent_id where tc_result='b' and testcases.pro_id=$a)as t4) as final where version_id= 1 limit 1;";

          $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
          echo'<div class="tbl-header">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                         <th>Total Testcase</th>
                         <th>Passed</th>
                         <th>Failed</th>
                         <th>Blocked</th>
                         <th>Not run</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
          </div>
       <div class="tbl-content">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
               {
               echo '<tr>

                <td>'.$row['total_tc'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['passed'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['failed'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['blocked'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['notrun'].'</td>

              </tr>';
             }
             echo'
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</html>';
}
// Calling function
for ($x = 1; $x <8; $x++) {
    project($x);
} 
?>
```

And Config2.php file contains

```
<?php
   define('SERVER', '192.168.0.7:3306');
   define('USERNAME', 'Deepak');
   define('PASSWORD', 'test@123');
   define('DATABASE', 'dashtest');
   $db = mysqli_connect(SERVER,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
?>
```

Can Any one help me to solve this?

Comment: You're re-including the file and redefining the constants every time you call the loop. Instead, call the file once outside of the function, and pass `$db` into the function.

Comment: There are bigger problems here than including the file twice - your `project` function currently displays the entire page, so calling it more than once doesn't make much sense. You need to refactor this so that only the logic to display the table rows is called from within a loop.

Comment: Thank you . It is working fine.:)

Answer (score 3):

You are including the file with the constants in your function:

```
     include("C:\wamp64\www\DashBoard\Config2.php");
```

So the second time you call your function, you will receive these warnings.

Either include the file outside of your function (and pass the database connection as a parameter if necessary) or use `include_once` instead.

Comment: include outside the foreach would be cleaner than include_once, in my opinion

Comment: @RonnieOosting I definitely agree and as it is the database connection, I would use `require_once` at the very start of the script.

Comment: agree on that jeroen. +1 from me.

Comment: If I use include_once. It won't display database data.And it gives "DB IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\DASHBOARD\TREESTRUCTURE\DYNAMICTABLES.PHP ON LINE 17" and "WARNING: MYSQLI_QUERY() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE MYSQLI, NULL GIVEN IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\DASHBOARD\TREESTRUCTURE\DYNAMICTABLES.PHP ON LINE 17" these warnings

Comment: @Vidya You should include before the loop and pass the database connection as a parameter to the function.